# Is the set of all sequences of complex number a subset of $\mathbb{C}^\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

I'm working through exercises in Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right" and trying to verify Example 1.35 (e) on page 19, which is stated as follows:

*(e) The set of all sequence of complex numbers with limit 0 is a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$.*

**My main question is: Wouldn't the set of all sequences of complex numbers for example include the sequence $(1,2,3)$ which is to my understanding not in $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$ thereby making this not a subset and therefore not a subspace?**

My understanding is that $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ contains all lists of length $\infty$ of complex numbers just as $\mathbb{R}^3$ contains all lists of length 3 of real numbers.

Also I now understand a list, tuple, sequence and vector to all be names for ordered collections of objects (generally numbers) of a certain length, and I'm wondering whether this is correct? Before this example I hadn't really made a connection between vectors and sequences, but it seems there is no difference in definition.

There is a set of solutions available at http://linearalgebras.com/1c.html (question 2e in this case) which doesn't address my question.

Comment: A sequence in $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ is a function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\infty $. Thus, the triple $(1,2,3)$ is not a sequence, as you conclude in the question. Intuitively, $(1,2,3)$ is not a sequence, however $(1,2,3,0,0,\cdots)$ _is_, and satisfy the example's condition.

Comment: You have to clarify the meaning of "sequence" and of the symbol $\mathbb{C}^\infty$. I guess a "sequence of complex numbers" is meant to be *infinite*, i.e. a function $x : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ which is usually written in the form $(x_n)$, where $x_n = x(n)$. And if $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ denotes the set of all these sequences (it can be given a metric), then (e) above is trivial.

Comment: It would have been clearer if the book had said "infinite sequence". Although the author likely expected the reader to understand it, because there is no definition of a limit of a finite sequence, so finite sequences are automatically excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "sequence" can sometimes refer to finite sequences (or indeed sequences with even more general index sets), but in many contexts it is used to refer *only* to infinite sequences (with index set $\mathbb{N}$).  That is clearly the intended meaning in the context of this problem.  So, for the purposes of this problem, a "sequence of complex numbers" is an *infinite* list of complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The set of all sequences of complex numbers is a way of describing the entire space $C^{\infty}$.

On the other hand,  to get a *proper* subspace,  you need to do something like take all sequences that converge to zero...

Comment: This is true but does not address the asker's point of confusion at all.